# (1,2): warning CS0105: The using directive for `System' appeared previously in this namespace

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces

I am an absolute beginner. I have tried to print Hello World. But it says `` (1,2): warning CS0105: The using directive for `System' appeared previously in this namespace ``.
Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");    
    }
  }
};
```

could you please tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: The full warning should include the filename and line number like `Program.cs(2,7,2,13): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'System' appeared previously in this namespace` Check it and make sure you're looking at the right file.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your code? On what line does the error point to? Looking at @RetiredNinja's comments, those numbers (in his case `2,7,2,13`) point to the line and character position of the error. Don't just tell us the line number  tell us which line of code causes the error

Comment: sorry for not adding the line number in the warning. I have edited the question. please check. Thanks in advance

Comment: `};` is the problem, remove the extra `;` at the end of the namespace block.